# Can I use a Code::Blocks as a MinGW GDB GUI?

Tags: gdb, mingw, codeblocks

We are unit testing with Vectorcast, which lets us use the MinGw GDB, but only the command line version. Some of the younger developers would like something more visual.

We do not use Code::Blocksto build our code, and it would be a major effort to do so.

Can we use a Code::Blocksas a GDB GUI? That is to say, can I point it at a .EXE file (which contains MinGW debug information) and use Code::Blocks (or any other MinGW based IDE) as a GDB GUI?

Comment: You can probably use Code::Blocks for MinGW, see http://www.mingw.org/wiki/ide.

Comment: Upvote for linking to the wiki. Alas, on a first search, I don't find what I seek. Perhaps I will [ask for help](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Ask_for_help)

Comment: What compiler do you use?
You can't use gdb for exe files built with MSVC for example.

Comment: We are actually using the MinGW compiler & linker. BUT, they are invoked from the Vectorcast unit test system. We have not, until now, used the MinGW IDE and don't really have to make a Code::Blocks project (oops, I have to update the question; we want to use Code::Blocks, or something else, which will give us a visual debugger, not just command line MinGW GDB - we already have that with Vectorcast))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a GUI tool for the debugger you could use [x64dbg](https://x64dbg.com/#start).
It allows you to perform both 32 and 64 bit debugging for programs built with either MinGW or Visual Studio

Comment: Great answer, thanks! Unfortunately, we are not allowed Admin rights, which x64dbg requires. Reading the web site though, I found a comparison to [OllyDbg](http://www.ollydbg.de/), which looks promising.

Answer (score 1):

One can use GUI based debugger inside VectorCAST instead of the default cmd line-based GDB debugger. In past, there was a short tutorial video on youtube about eclipse debugger but I couldn't find it now. Anyway, the user has to modify the default debugger command (gdb) from the 'Linker/Debugger' section of the tool and specify a debugger, and de-select 'command line... '. Once done when a user tries debugging test case it will launch debugged IDE and the user can then simply build debug project bypassing .exe generate in a test environment.

Answer (score 0):

> We do not use Code::Blocks to build our code, and it would be a major effort to do so.
>   Can we use a Code::Blocksas a GDB GUI? That is to say, can I point it at a .EXE file (which contains MinGW debug information) and use Code::Blocks (or any other MinGW based IDE) as a GDB GUI?

Yes, you can do this.
First, you can create a simple console C::B project.

Second, you can put the path of the .EXE file you want as the output executable. It is in the Project/target option dialog, the "output filename" field.

Third, you should deselect "Auto-build project if it is not up-to-date" in the debugger plugin option dialog.

Then you can click the "Start debugging" button to debug this .EXE. You can add the source files of your .EXE to the C::B project, so that you can step through the source files, set break points.

Comment: Me : `We do not use Code::Blocks to build our code, and it would be a major effort to do so` You: `Yes, you can do this. First, you can create a simple console C::B project` ??!!

Comment: Hi, @Mawg, I mean you can create a simple C::B project which you don't need to build this C::B project, you can add the source files to the C::B project, those files are only used for debugging. You can build your EXE file through other method(I mean you can use other tools to build this EXE file), but you set the EXE file as the "output file" in the C::B's project, so when you start debugging, C::B will use GDB to debug this EXE file. Hope this explanation helps.

Comment: I will give it a try on Monday. Fingers crossed

Comment: They wouldn't let me "waste time". So, I am happy enough with comman dline GDB, while the youngsters still grouse :-(

Comment: @Mawg it it not that hard to debug under Code::Blocks, in-fact, quite simple.

Comment: I know; I have used it often enough, but that's not really the question, and now I am forbidden to even look into a solution :-(